# Doesn't find interface's method although it exists in jar

Tags: java, android, jar

I have a problem that I've been trying for two days already to solve, I would like to get your help.

I have two applications, let's named them A and B. B needs to call to a method that that exists in A into an interface. 
I attached to B Jar file that included A's relevant classes and the interface also there (No compilation errors at all). However, while running, I got "**NoSuchMethodError**" Exception.

I took a look on the compiled interface from the jar that was pushed to the device and I saw the called method. So, I really don't understand why I get "NoSuchMethodError".

Do you have any idea what can I do? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that when you include your A's jar file with all his classes, that do not mean that they will be exported when the build append.
Try to specify to export the jar file when you build your application.

Also, 2 application can't talk to each other with a simple import or using a static variable. They are both executed in different VM that can't communicate with each other.
The only way to do this is to use some Android Intent with a some BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Regarding the second thing, I used AIDL. You wrote "Try to specify to export the jar file when you build your application"- I checked that the updated jar in the device, it is not enough? If not, I would like to know why, and how can I export the new jar while building? Thank you.

Comment: I sorry but i will not be able to help with AIDL, i don't have ever do something with it.
Here is a exemple with Eclipse IDE (my main ide) where you need to specify what will be in the final exported file and what will not be present [image](https://i.imgur.com/P674FbO.png), maybe using AIDL file is not the same, you maybe need to include it manually like adding it as "an external file" and putting the absolute link so it can be reached when building. (sorry i really don't know how AIDL file work....)